# Google Maps, Fusion Tables, and Geolocation

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm having a problem setting a variable in ST_DISTANCE to a variable instead of a number. My goal is to sort fusion table entries by distance to the client and only display the closest 3.

(Also, I would like the window to zoom out and encompass those points as well as point to where the client is. Any hints or links to some recourses would be appreciated).

Here is the Google Maps, Fusion Tables, and Geolocation code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {   
    if(!!navigator.geolocation) {       
        var map;
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };          
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {           
            var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(geolocate);           
        });
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions)

        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            map: map,
            heatmap: { enabled: false },
            query: {
                select: "col1",
                from: "1JaRXQJ_YJch5Ua6cfZCBpaUEKRnd2jIcHVmcODY",
                orderBy: 'ST_DISTANCE(col1, LATLNG("geolocate"))',
                limit: 3,
                where: ""
            },
            options: {
                styleId: 2,
                templateId: 2
            }
        });

    } else {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.918487877955485, -98.30599773437501),
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });     
        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            map: map,
            heatmap: { enabled: false },
            query: {
                select: "col1",
                from: "1JaRXQJ_YJch5Ua6cfZCBpaUEKRnd2jIcHVmcODY",
                where: ""
            },
            options: {
                styleId: 2,
                templateId: 2
            }

        });     
    }

})();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I know this is messy. I don't know javascript.

I would like to know how to put the variable "geolocate" created by:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {           
        var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map.setCenter(geolocate);           
});
```

Into the LATLNG place in:

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'Address',
        from: '15UY2pgiz8sRkq37p2TaJd64U7M_2HDVqHT3Quw',
        orderBy: 'ST_DISTANCE(Address, LATLNG(37.4,-122.1))',
        limit: 3
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a basic javascript question ...

Make geolocate global, like var map;

```
var map;
var geolocate;
```

Remove var in front of your existing geolocate.

Then remove quotes around your usage of geolocate.

```
orderBy: 'ST_DISTANCE(col1, LATLNG(' + geolocate + ') )',
```

Comment: Thank you! that helped immensely. Problem is a made a whole nother mess trying to add some more functionality now all is broken